# Applying $filter option to retrieve list of files changed after a specific date/time in Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

My objective is to retrieve the list of files that are changed after a specific date/time using "lastmodifieddatetime" filter in delta queries of Graph API.

This delta query runs fine without the filter and return the results    https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!tdu7QGu1NUiJuvpapUo4eHtDQtia22xMmeJKVjKjCUHKKpRlf9SfT6j9xNTidHfN/root/delta?$filter=lastModifiedDateTime ge '2021-07-30T14:41:08Z'

However, this fails to execute with an error with a filter clause:-

[image]

Please let me know if there is any solution available to filter out the files changed after the specific date and time. Any workaround will help too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your question. Filter isn't currently supported on the endpoints to track changes to a drive which is why the request fails. From the [documentation on tracking changes:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters)

```
This method supports the $select, $expand, and $top OData query parameters to customize the response.
```

I would suggest handling the filtering in your logic as a workaround.
Would you consider [filing a feature request](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) on the M365 Developer Platform so that this can be looked into?

Let me know whether this helps and if you have further questions.